# Implement a Vue.js component so that the element defined as

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<labeledinput id="username">Username: </labeledinput>
```

Will render like:

```
<div><label for="username">Username: </label><input type="text" id="username"></div>

  <div id="app">
    <labeledinput id="username">Username: </labeledinput>
  </div>
  <script>  
    var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#app'
    });
    
    // Example case
    console.log(document.getElementById("app").innerHTML);
  </script>
```

I know this is a very stupid question. but I can't get a concept of Vue.js
Thanks,

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: @Anurag, thanks for your answer. How to add a 'Username` as a child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way more simple to create a component is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div>
        <label-input v-model="username">
          <span>Username</span>
        </label-input>
        <span>Username is {{ username }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      Vue.component('label-input', {
        props: ['value'],
        template: `
          <div>
            <label>
              <slot></slot>
              <input type="text" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" />
            </label>
          </div>`,
      });

      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data() {
          return {
            username: '',
          };
        },
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about using `slot`? <label><slot></slot></label> like this

Comment: @wdev733 I updated my answer. Are you looking for it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer which I did myself and passed all the test cases.

```
// Component Definition
    Vue.component('labeledinput', {
      props: ['id'],
      template: `
        <div>
          <label :for="id"><slot></slot></label>
          <input :id="id" type="text">
        </div>
      `
    });
```